# temp:7: attempt to index global 'mon' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, computercraft

So im really new to this, and I dont know why it isnt working

Ive googled all around the place, all I can find is that you should put an end somewhere but I dont know where.

```
Power = peripheral.wrap("ic2:oldmfsu")
mon = peripheral.wrap("monitor_0")

local maxPower = 0
local curPower = 0
local perPower = 0

monX.monY = mon.getsize()

function checkpower()


etc


I expect it to count the number of energy that is stored.
```

Comment: Hello there, welcome to SO. Your question appears to need some work before people can help you. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to write clear, concise questions that will maximize your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that `mon` is `nil`. That means that `peripheral.wrap("monitor_0")` returned `nil` instead of the expected table.

Indexing a nil value is not allowed because it doesn't make sense. Hence Lua complains about your attempt.

https://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Peripheral.wrap

> **Function peripheral.wrap**
>
> Returns a table containing functions pointing to the peripheral's
>   methods, which can then be called as if using peripheral.call(side,
>   method). **If no peripheral is found at the specified side, returns
>   nil instead**.

So check wether `mon` is `nil` befor you index it and maybe print an error message else.